# Google Maps URL Structure For Zoom

Tags: google-maps, url, google-maps-api-3, hyperlink

Trying to change the zoom level of the map returned below. I am using it as a link in excel. Have looked around and thought this should work as I change the z=1 to z=2, etc.

http://maps.google.com/maps?z=1&t=h&q=2517 MCDEARMON ST,SACHSE,TX,75408

Answer (score 1):

That is with the "old" google maps, it was never documented and no longer works.  If you want a URL for an embedded google map, use the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/), it has a documented `zoom` parameter.

[example 2 embedded maps, just changing the `zoom` parameter in the URL](http://www.geocodezip.com/example_embedded_map_20160131.html)

```
<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=2517+MCDEARMON+ST,SACHSE,TX,75408&zoom=10&key=API_key" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<iframe width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?q=2517+MCDEARMON+ST,SACHSE,TX,75408&zoom=1&key=API_key" allowfullscreen></iframe><script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: So is there a way to do this with a URL or no? From the link, it appeared to be using Google API. Could you give an example?

Comment: If I don't want it embedded (I am using the link out of excel). Can I just use the url part?